# rails: Get all items tagged x AND y AND z

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got two models: `Item` and `Tag`. Both have a name attribute. I want to find items tagged with several tags.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Given a list of tag ids, I can easily enough get the list of items tagged with one tag **or** the other:

```
# Find the items tagged with one or more of the tags on tag_ids
Item.all(:conditions => ['tags.id in (?)', tag_ids], :joins => :tags)
```

If `tag_ids` is `{1,4}`, then I get all pictures tagged with 1, or 4, or both.

I want to know now how to get the pictures that are tagged with both - 1 **AND** 4.

I can't even imagine the SQL that is needed here.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... What a coincidence!!

Comment: I believe that code also gives you "duplicates" if an item is tagged with "both" tags, as well, which may not be good (use  :group      => 'items.id' to make it not return duplicates).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can solve this by grouping the results and checking the count:

```
Item.all(
  :conditions => ['tags.id IN (?)', tag_ids], 
  :joins      => :tags, 
  :group      => 'items.id', 
  :having     => ['COUNT(*) >= ?', tag_ids.length]
)
```

Comment: This is simple and elegant. It helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Little update :
Today, we can use (inspired by elektronaut) :

```
Item.joins(:tags).where("tags.label in (?)", tags).group('items.id').having("COUNT(*) >= ?", tags.size)
```

It is not very different, by it works well here.

Comment: This is a great solution! +1 (just make sure you have an index on tags.label).

Answer (score 2):

I've got one thing to add to elektronaut's otherwise wonderful answer: it will not work on PostgreSQL.

On my real example the Item.all call includes other tables; so the select looks like this:

```
SELECT items.id AS t0_f0, items.name as t0_f1 ..., table2.field1 as t1_f0 .. etc
```

PostgreSQL's GROUP BY requires that *all fields* used on a select to be included there. So I had to include all the fields used on the previous select on the GROUP BY clause.

And still it didn't work; I'm not sure why.

I ended up doing a simpler, uglier thing. It requires two db requests. One of them is used to return ids, which are used as a condition.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  # returns the ids of the items tagged with all tags
  # usage: Item.tagged_all(1,2,3)
  named_scope :tagged_all, lambda { |*args|
    { :select => "items.id",
      :joins => :tags,
      :group => "items.id",
      :having => ['COUNT(items.id) >= ?', args.length],
      :conditions => ["tags.id IN (?)", args]
    }
  }
```

Then I can do this:

```
  Item.all(
    :conditions => [
      'items.id IN (?) AND ... (other conditions) ...',
      Items.tagged_all(*tag_ids).collect(&:id),
      ... (other values for conditions) ...
    ],
    :includes => [:model2, :model3] #tags isn't needed here any more
  )
```

Hacky, but it works, and the hackyness is localized.